# How to change system timezone permanently?

Tags: dpkg, system-settings, timezone

"dpkg-reconfigure tzdata" does the job perfectly. But I require a method that doesn't include a text based gui. I have searched and seen some ways which require using "tzselect" and then export "TZ" environment variable while others suggest to create symbolic link "ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/ /etc/localtime". Can you tell me which one to use so that the system time is changed permanently and persistent across reboots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/84528/459227

In short, you can set the timezone you want in `/etc/timezone` and then you can call `dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata` so it applies the settings without asking on a text based GUI.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try and see if its persistent across reboots.